# HTML audio element created with innerHTML throws a DOMException when played

Tags: javascript, audio

I have created a module that creates the HTML templates from `[String]` content. Generally it works like below:

```
const wrapper = document.createElement('TEMPLATE');
wrapper.innerHTML = '<div id="container"></div>'; //some string content
const content = wrapper.content.querySelector('#container'); //return DOM Element
```

The problem occurs, when I try to create an `<audio>` element this way. Then, when a DOM audio element is created and when I call `.play()`, it throws an error `Uncaught (in promise) DOMException`. It works fine when I use `document.createElement('DIV')` rather than `'TEMPLATE'` as a wrapper.

I **need** to create a `TEMPLATE` wrapper rather than eg. `'DIV'`, because when I want to create some template for `TR` elements, the `DIV` wrapper does not work for it.

The audio element created in both ways is the regular DOM Audio Element, so why there is an error, when I try to play the audio created with the `'TEMPLATE'`?

**EDIT:**

Now I can see that it:

- does not work in `Chrome` and `Firefox`
- works well in `Edge`

```js
const divButton = document.getElementById('button-a');
const templateButton = document.getElementById('button-b');
const output = document.getElementById('output');

const divWrapper = document.createElement('DIV');
const templateWrapper = document.createElement('TEMPLATE');

const src = "https://www.collinsdictionary.com/sounds/hwd_sounds/03090.mp3";
const innerContent = `<audio id="player" src="${src}"></audio>`;

divWrapper.innerHTML = innerContent;
templateWrapper.innerHTML = innerContent;

const divAudio = divWrapper.querySelector('#player');
const templateAudio = templateWrapper.content.querySelector('#player');

divButton.addEventListener('click',()=>divAudio.play());
templateButton.addEventListener('click',()=>templateAudio.play());

divAudio.onerror = (event)=> output.innerHTML = event.target.error.message;

templateAudio.onerror = (event)=> output.innerHTML = event.target.error.message;
```

```html
<button id="button-a">Play audio created with 'DIV' container</button></br></br>
<button id="button-b">Play audio created with 'TEMPLATE' container</button>

<p id="output"></p>
```

Comment: It works if you append the element to the document first. Just call `document.body.append(templateAudio);` before `.play()`.

Comment: ok thank you it works, but still I can't figure out how the browser distinguish the audio element created with 'DIV' and 'TEMPLATE' wrappers and why the second one is problematic. The first one does not have to be appended in order to be played. I checked all properties of both dom objects but they seem to be the same.